# Having troubles doing a DSL query from linux terminal

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having the following problem doing a simple DSL query on linux terminal

```
curl -XGET --user <user>:<pass> "https://<host>/elasticsearch/logstash-*/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "match": { "_type" : "nxlog"}
  }
}'
```

this block of code returns the first ten documents in my index logstash but without filtering, this code was copied from the console of kibana that presents the correct results, I only add the authentication needed to connect to the server

```
GET logstash-*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {"_type": "nxlog"}
  }
}
```

for what a read,it seem that is returning values as is the query typed after the -d flag doesn't exist.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks in advance

**EDIT: Put the correct kibana console code that I was trying**

Comment: You have a `match` clause in your curl query but not in your Kibana query. Bad copy/paste?

Comment: Also try `-XPOST` instead of `-XGET` if you want to send a body

Comment: yes @Val, I used match, missed the right code that I was trying, tried with -XPOST and it return the followind error `{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Request must contain a kbn-xsrf header."}`

Comment: I think you're hitting the kibana server instead of the ES server directly, try `https://<es-host>/logstash-*/_search`  directly

Comment: I think Im missing something, when I try a URL search for the same search as DSL with `logstash-*/_search?pretty&q=_type:nxlog` the response is what I expect, and its the same as the console from kibana, thats why I think its the elasticsearch server what im hitting, if Im wrong let me know please, thank for your quick reply BTW

Comment: If in your `<host>` you have port 5601 then you're hitting Kibana. You should it ES directly on port 9200 (i.e. remove one variable from the equation).

Comment: Thanks @Val, that was the problem, thanks for the help